Change Template Params based on other params value in n vs IDE
First Case
Second case
Does anyone know how to replicate this behaviour when creating a custom template?
I want to make vs IDE to display one parameter based on the value of another, like it happens in the images I provided.
I have no idea how to make it work or if I'm using the wrong syntax. Right now, the second param checkbox is always displaying no matter what.
I also tried to find the template code to see how its done, but I could find it anywhere.

I checked the official Microsoft documentation and found that only these two ways of creating templates are available:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-item-templates?view=vs-2022
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2022
If you need to let "VS IDE display a parameter based on the value of another parameter", I think it might be a better choice to make a request here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest?port=1025&fsid=3563a39e-bbd6-402f-b176-54aea54e3ca1
